# is it possible to upload android app that has @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi & @Flowpreview?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have an app with coroutine and flow, But it gives me @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi & @Flowpreview. Is it possible to upload the app to play store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Google Play probably doesn't scan the app for third-party (non-google) library warnings.

Anecdotally, I have an app that uses `Flow` experimental API up and running on play store.